# agGrid - display filter phrase in column header name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would you go about displaying the phrase you're filtering a column by inside the header cell of that particular column?

Say I filter the column Country by "USA" and the header cell changes to Country (USA).

I tried inspecting the scope with angular inspector but couldn't find anything related to the exact filter phrase.

Comment: Are you having trouble with getting the value you've written, for example 'USA' from the input box or are you having trouble with selecting the correct header cell to modify the text of?

Comment: The latter, I already know how to access the filter value.

Comment: You can probably access the country header cell by selecting elements with the class 'ag-header-cell-text' and checking with innerHTML if the selected element has the text 'Country'.

Comment: What happens if I have filters set for multiple columns? This would need proper name matching to assign the correct filter for each column header.

Comment: Yeah that's the only big problem with this since all of the filter inputs in the ag-grid have the same classes and id:s. Modifying the HTML inside the JavaScript files could be a solution, but I'm not entirely sure about that either.

Answer (score 2):

When you define you Column Definition instead of setting the `headerName` with a static value, you can set the `headerValueGetter` property so the header value is computed

For example:

`{ headerName: "Country", field: "country", editable: true, filter: 'text' }`

becomes

`{ headerValueGetter : (params) => {return "Country" + FILTER_VALUE}, field: "country", editable: true, filter: 'text' }`

That being said you could just update the header on demand...

`var countryCol = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumn("country").getColDef();
colDef.headerName = "Country (USA)";
gridOptions.api.refreshHeader();`